# Открыть *.html файл во весь экран

Tags: bat

Пишется `*.bat`-файл для для запуска файла `*.html` на компьютере пользователя в браузере:

```
start index.html
exit
```

Как открывать его во весь экран?

Comment: Нажать F11 и все

Comment: @HELOWORD вот так решение! Вот так да!) А есть что то посерьезнее? Автоматически?

Comment: Прошу уточнить версию браузера. Команда start попробует открыть браузер по умолчанию. В зависимости от типа браузера команда запуска будет отличаться. Например, для хрома будут использованы ключи запуска --start-maximized или --kiosk.

Answer (score 3):

```
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --kiosk --start-fullscreen -- file://D:/Temp/Supertemp/index.html
```

Проверено на Google Chrome  45.0.2454.101 (Официальная сборка) m (64 бит)

Answer (score 0):

[SendMessage App](http://stefanstools.sourceforge.net/SendMessage.html) + [WM_KEYDOWN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) + [Virtual-Key Codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Окно браузера определяется по заголовку или по классу (тогда нужна программа типа Spy+). Дальше, с помощью SendMessage окну посылается сообщение WM_KEYDOWN(F11).