# Открыть chrome в FullScreen программно

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, google-chrome

Я хочу показать пользователю некую "презентацию" в режиме FullScreen (которая представляет собой локальный HTML - файл), в предположении, что основным браузером у него является Chrome.

Собственно вопрос - практически полностью поместился в заголовке, за исключением одного условия: если браузер УЖЕ запущен, я бы хотел просто открыть в нём новую вкладку и как-то перевести его в FullScreen.

Обычно то, что я хочу сделать, делают так:

Первый способ. Человек РУКАМИ нажимает на клавиатуре F11. По понятным причинам, это способ мне не подходит.

Второй способ - рекомендация из [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/456167/) вопроса-ответа, работает, при условии, что на компе нет запущенного хрома. То есть, новый экземпляр браузера будет открыт в FullScreen. Если же браузер уже запущен - получится пшик. То есть, никакого перехода в FullScreen. Просто откроется еще одна вкладка.

Обычно, на этом месте рассуждений советы идут по двум путям:

1. убить все экземпляры браузера, и запустить заново одно окно в режиме фуллскрина.
   Этому мешают две вещи:

   во первых, у пользователя может быть что то важное открыто во вкладках. Закрывать их - как то неаккуратненько.

   во вторых, Хроме может сначала запускаться выбор профиля, под которым надо рабоать. То есть, вместо красивой презентации человек увидит что то вроде такого:

   [image: хром]

   В общем, способ со "сначала убить, а потом создать заново" - довольно плохой.
2. "Фигня вопрос!" - говорят люди, которые умеют посылать сообщения окнам при помощи SendMessage - "Просто найдите идентификатор нужного окна, и пошлите ему <kbd>F11</kbd>!".

   Просто... но не очень просто.

   Вот я сижу за компом. У меня открыто несколько вкладок в хроме, и сам процесс хрома запущен примерно в 25 экземплярах. Здесь нет моего злого умысла - Хром сам так делает.

   Если я хочу послать "нажатие клавиши" в только что открытый хром - мне надо его "запустить, а потом попросить у него MainWindowHandle".

   Обычно этот совет сопровождается примером кода типа такого

   ```
    Process p = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad").FirstOrDefault();
    if (p != null)
    {
        IntPtr h = p.MainWindowHandle;
        SetForegroundWindow(h);
        SendKeys.SendWait("k");
    }
   ```

   и всегда на примере программы Notepad.

   С ноутпадом это работает.

   С Хромом - всегда в результате вызова `p.MainWindowHandle` возникает exception "Process has exited, so the requested information is not available.".

   Если Вы хотите это проверить - попробуйте на нажатие кнопки поместить примерно такой код:

   (Запускать советую в WinForms - приложении, собранном для .NET Framework 4.8 - почему по в NET Core вызов Process.Start(), вызванный с аргументом, не являющимся именем экзешника, сразу приводит к Exception)

   ```
        string index = Path.Combine(@"C:\Temp", "index.html");
        Process bProc = Process.Start(index);

        // pause 0.2 sec
        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        // send key F11 to process
        if (bProc != null) {

            try {
                while (bProc.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero) {
                    Thread.Sleep(10);
                    bProc.Refresh();
                }

                var handle = bProc.MainWindowHandle;
                // удача! Есть искомый hadle!
                // собственно, посылка F11 по известному handle
                SetForegroundWindow(h);
                SendKeys.SendWait("k");
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                // The process has probably exited,
                // so accessing MainWindowHandle threw an exception
            }
        }
   ```

   И `удача` в этом фрагменте кода не наступает никогда.

В общем, задача не очень простая. И я уже перепробовал все способы, которые более-менее лежат на поверхности.

Не посоветуете ли Вы мне, как еще это можно сделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Второй способ - рекомендация из [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/456167/) вопроса-ответа, работает, при условии, что на компе нет запущенного хрома. То есть, новый экземпляр браузера будет открыт в FullScreen. Если же браузер уже запущен - получится пшик. То есть, никакого перехода в FullScreen. Просто откроется еще одна вкладка.

При запуске браузера есть возможность указать папку для хранения профиля. Если она не будет совпадать с той, для которой браузер уже открыт, то останется новый экземпляр.

Т. е. я предлагаю запускать браузер с чистым профилем в kiosk-режиме.

```
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --user-data-dir=C:\Temp\Supertemp\smth --kiosk --start-fullscreen -- file://C:/Temp/Supertemp/index.html
```

Папка, указанная в `--user-data-dir=C:\Temp\Supertemp\smth` может быть любой: пустой или даже вообще не существовать (хром создаст сам, главное, чтобы права на запись были). Но надо не забыть почистить её самому после выхода из браузера, а то будет мусор на диске накапливаться.

Ну или можно иметь свою постоянную папку профиля хрома именно для своего приложения, но не рядом с ним, поскольку хрому будут нужны права на запись в неё.

Что касается флага `--kiosk`, то если требуется дать возможность пользователю выходить из полноэкранного режима, то его надо убрать.

Comment: Все работает! Огромное спасибо, совершенно свежее и оригинальное решение проблемы! Уважаемый Qwertiy помогает мне не в первый раз, и я еще раз имею возможность убедиться: люди с огромными рейтингами на SO подчас дают очень крутые советы!